# Creating a backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple for testing purposes?

Tags: java, scala, testing, apache-storm

I'm new to [Storm](http://storm-project.net/) and am trying to work out how to write a bolt test that tests the `execute(Tuple tuple)` method in a subclassed `BaseRichBolt`.

The issue is it appears that `Tuple` is immutable and I don't see any methods or builders to create a new Tuple. How can I create my own `Tuple`, or how can I test a bolt with test input?

I'm actually using Scala, not Java, but the answer should be easily translatable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mocking the Tuple object is a good solution from the [storm-starter project](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter/blob/master/test/jvm/storm/starter/tools/MockTupleHelpers.java). It's straightforward:

```
package storm.starter.tools;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import backtype.storm.Constants;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple;

public final class MockTupleHelpers {

    private MockTupleHelpers() {
    }

    public static Tuple mockTickTuple() {
        return mockTuple(Constants.SYSTEM_COMPONENT_ID, Constants.SYSTEM_TICK_STREAM_ID);
    }

    public static Tuple mockTuple(String componentId, String streamId) {
        Tuple tuple = mock(Tuple.class);
        when(tuple.getSourceComponent()).thenReturn(componentId);
        when(tuple.getSourceStreamId()).thenReturn(streamId);
        return tuple;
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone have another way to do it?  I need more than one as I am putting them in a List and doing a list.contains().  I need multiple different objects.